# Does anyone know if Google ARCore supports Xiaomi redmi Note 10?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, xiaomi

This device does not appear on the ARCore compatible devices, But I think is because this model is pretty new, march 2021. https://developers.google.com/ar/devices

Don't know if google have to admit new models before release but redmi note 9 pro and 8 are compatible.

Any one having a note 10 or more info of compabilities with ARCore?

Plz don't rate negative if you don't know, just pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have a look at this link with all the supported devices: https://developers.google.com/ar/devices

Answer (score 0):

Redmi Note 10 series does not support ARCore (or) 'Google services for AR'. It is a true disappointment for users looking for it. This info will not be on specifications. Only hoping that update will be made available.

Comment: Could you back that up with some kind of source please?